# How to have a sticky header and/or footer with @media print

Tags: css, printing, header, media, footer

How can you make a sticky header and/or footer for @media print only with HTML and CSS? I've tried using `position: absolute` and `position: fixed` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` won't work. That would either repeat the header/footer on the first or last page. What you need to do is: **Set manually header and/or footer on every page**, have  content with a fixed height and overflow hidden, and use `page-break-*` CSS property to make the browser create a new page on the beginning of the page.

So on the browser it would show all the `content`s without any headers and footers, and when printing it would include. If one of the `content` doesn't take the whole paper, it would leave some empty space until the `footer`, and if it is too big it would be hidden.

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">...</div>
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">...</div>
</body>
```

And on CSS:

```
.page .header, .page .footer {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .page {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
    .page .content {
        height: 24cm;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .page .header, .page .footer {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Also notice that on `@media print` measurements should be done in physical units, so you should use `cm` or `in` instead of `px`.

Comment: What would happen if the page's content didn't fit on the page? You're basically paginating yourself in advance, which doesn't make sense on the Web, does it?

Comment: @hendry with the `height: 24cm` I'm making sure that if it is shorter, it would take the whole page, and with the `overflow: hidden` I'm making sure that if it is longer, it would be hidden. It would make sense if you're outputting documents with a relatively approximate measurement and you want to make sure that each one fits in one page. So on the web version they could appear on top of each other (like cards, or a table, for instance) but fit one per page when printing. Or simple cards with only title and a small excerpt but when printing with all details, for instance.